# How to reference tables/queries/reports in access using an alias name?

Tags: vba, ms-access

In my Access database, I have tables with the naming convention of "t_customers" or "t_orders". I have a combo box which lets me pick from these options. For a better look, I want to have the options in the combo box without the "t_", so one of the options is just "customers". Then in VBA, I can access the combo box's value of "customers" and then pass that as a parameter to my function which will export the contents of the associated table "t_customers" to an excel file.

Is this possible to do? I can think of using a select case statement and for each combo box value I manually assign the related table value, but there has to be a better way. Is there some sort of short cut that does this in Access using a relationship or similar feature without coding? Or is there a simpler way to code this?

EDIT:
I am also trying to get the value of the current item selected in my combo box named "cbTable". I have no macros attached to the combo box. I have a button that when pressed it runs a macro which calls my VBA function. In the function I have this code:

```
Dim cbValue As String
cbValue = cbTable.Value
MsgBox (cbValue)
```

I get this error:

> Runtime Error '424'
>
> Object Required

The error is on the

```
cbValue = cbTable.Value
```

line. What is wrong with this code and how do I get the current value of the combo box?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, drop that naming convention.

Comment: This is for a work project so I am unable to

Comment: retrieve the value from the combobox as `customers` and when it's being used in a query add the prefix directly: `sql = "select * from t_" & tableName & " where  blah = something"` would be one way...

Comment: The line which triggers the error ... `cbValue = cbTable.Value` ... where is that code located.  Is it in the code module of the form which contains `cbTable`?  It won't work if it's in any other module.

Comment: @HansUp how can I check which code module it's in?

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the Declarations sections of all your modules.  Then run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.  Fix whatever the compiler complains about, then run Debug->Compile again.  Keep at it until no more compile errors.

Comment: Re "which code module" ... place your cursor on `cbValue = cbTable.Value`,  "Restore Window" for that code pane and look at its title bar.

Comment: The error "Variable is not defined" comes up for cbtable. How can I access the combo box from my function? In the access table I named the combo box cbtable

Comment: @HansUp I can't find this restore window you mentioned. In the VBA editor There is a Modules folder located in my database. In there I have my code. I don't know what you mean by code module of the form

Comment: Is this your first time using Access VBA?

Comment: Yeah new to me this week

Comment: @Michael HandUp means this button. http://imgur.com/xAPavs2

Comment: @Brad thanks, never knew what that was called. But it said "ExportTable (Code)" along with the name of my database

Comment: (Just to expand that last comment) @Michael HansUp means [this button](http://imgur.com/xAPavs2) where you'd look at the [title bar](http://i.imgur.com/mUo8VkU.png) but you could also look at the [VBA IDE title bar](http://i.imgur.com/SpQ345V.png). Ultimately he's asking if your code is in a [form module](http://i.imgur.com/j0BQBU8.png) or a code module.

Comment: Ohh okay it's in a code module, how do I switch that?

Comment: Yo, @Brad  Would you like to take over?  I'm burnt out.

Comment: @HansUp hehe I'll give it a whirl :)

Comment: @Michael check the edits on my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your `RowSource` for your combobox to

```
SELECT MSysObjects.Name, Replace(MSysObjects.Name,"t_","") AS Expr1
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE (((MSysObjects.Type)=1) AND ((MSysObjects.Flags)=0));
```

Then set the `Column Count` to 2, the `Column Widths` to `0;2` (the second number just needs to be any positive number) an the `Bound Column` to 1.

Now when you go to call your function the value of the combobox will be the real name of the table, `t-customers`, but what you saw on your form was `customers`.

---

As for accessing that combobox a few things need to be in place.

Let's say you have a form, `Form1`, and your combobox, `cbTable`, is on that form. 
[image]

So when your form runs it looks like this

[image]

Now let's say you have an OnChange even for that combobox

[image]

Notice that when you type `cbTable` it appears in the intellisense (ctrl+space). This tells you that your object is accessible at this scope.

Now if you were in another module where that variable is out of scope you would get this error when you try to compile.

[image]

Because `Module1` has no idea what `cbTable` is. However, you can reference anything so long as it's fully qualified. So if we run this test with your form open, and "orders" selected all 3 of these lines are equivalent

```
Forms("Form1").cbTable
Form_Form1!cbTable
Forms("Form1").Controls("cbTable")
```

[image]

Notice at the top of all my modules it says `Option Explicit`. This forces your code to basically be checked for syntax/scope validity before you run it. Tools > Options

[image]

Comment: My code was working great. I added another combo box, copy and pasted the code and fixed the variable names and that worked great as well. Now, I created a third combo box. Copy and pasted the code from the others and now my program isn't working. I keep getting the error "Member already exists in an object module from which this object module derives". The functions that the 3 buttons call are ExportTable(), ExportQuery() and ExportReport(). Any ideas?

Comment: @michael when you compile what line is highlighted?

Comment: I just figured it out. I named my buttons ExportReport, ExportTable and ExportQuery which was the same name as the functions. I changed it and it works fine!

Comment: @Michael You should be able to export to excel but it will be `xls` format and it will really butcher the formatting. You sure you don't want to export to PDF? typically that is why you make a report is to display the data in a static, styled format.

Comment: Sorry I made a dummy mistake, tried to delete my comment before you wrote back. Thanks anyway! works fine now